# preg_replace and multiple NOTs

Tags: php, regex, syntax, code-analysis

I want to replace all "private function __someMethod()" with "protected function _someMethod().
But I do want to leave the magic ones untouched.
The replacing does not work though.

```
$x = array(
    '/\bprivate function __([^(construct|destruct|sleep|wakeup|get|set|call|toString|invoke|set_state|clone|callStatic|isset|unset)])\b/i',
    'protected function _\1'
)
```

`\b` and `\b` as word boundaries.

it uses `preg_replace($x[0], $x[1])`.

thx!

i also tried `[^construct^destruct^sleep]` etc

the same applies to `" $this->__ "` and `" ::__ "` (static call) then, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^...]` syntax is a negated character class. Everything in square brackets is just a list of characters, the `()` and the `|` are not interpreted, and your words get shuffled into a list of letters.

What you wanted to use was a [negative assertion `(?!....)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
  '/\bprivate function __(?!construct|destruct|sleep|wakeup|get|set|call|toString|invoke|set_state|clone|callStatic|isset|unset)\w+\b/i',
```

It should be followed by `\w+` to work for your preg_replacing.

Comment: why the w+? probably because it has to be a word? a-zA-Z?

Comment: Yes. But also because the assertion itself would be a zero-width match.

Comment: the only problem is that the string gets shortened. \1 seems not to work in this case and the result is "protected function _()"

Comment: There is no `\1` unless you have a capture group. Use `(\w++)`